# Android - How To Manage Multiple Projects Having Similar Contents But Different Package Name And App Name

Tags: android, git

We have a project that we need to release two versions which would have almost 99% similar features but different package names and application name.

We have created a branch in git for that project which handles the version for the client while the main branch is our version.

Now, the problem is that every time we fix some bugs on the main version we need to do the same on the client version. However, this will just double the effort. If we just push it directly to that branch, there will be a lot of conflicts to fix because of the package name difference.

Is there a good solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: How about a sub-module for the common part, and a "main" repository for each application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JLT,

Check out **build variants** in gradle. This will allow you to create different flavors and packages.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants

You can also use libraries, but that can become a little complex at times. I have done both and prefer to use gradle to do all the work and then I can focus on development and not an additional library and perhaps multiple code bases.

Here is an example you can use in your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    final PACKAGE_NAME = "com.example"

    productFlavors {
        app1 {
            applicationId PACKAGE_NAME + ".app1"
        }
        app2 {
            applicationId PACKAGE_NAME + ".app2"
        }
    }

}
```